# Div content alignment using display property with table and table-cell values

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display 2 table cells with same top line mark.

Actual Alignment:
[image]

Expected:

[image]

Please have a look into my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naguwin/bc2wk6ra/7/)

Code

```css
.related-list-main { width: 300px;display: table;padding: 10px; }
.related-list-title { font: 12px Verdana,Arial,san-serif;display: table-cell; width: 85%;text-align: left;  /* color: #337ab7; */ }
.related-list-sno  { font: 22px Verdana,Arial,san-serif;color:#A51F1D; display: display: table-cell; width: 15%;text-align: right;float: right; }
.related-list-border-bot { border-bottom: 1.5px solid #eceaea;margin: 0 0px; height: 1.5px;text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="patents" class="tab-pane in active ">
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Sea Food Flavored Food Products</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    1
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food Ingredients and Food Products Treated with an Oxidoreductase and Methods for Preparing Such Food Ingredients and Food Products</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    2
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food and Process for Producing Food</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    3
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Prepared Food for Functional Food</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    4
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food Ingredients and Food Products Treated with an Oxidoreductase and Methods for Preparing Such Food Ingredients and Food Products</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    5
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food Production Apparatus, the Production of Food and Novel Food Product</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    6
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food Production Apparatus for the Production of Food and Novel Food Product</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    7
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food Ingredients and Food Products Treated with an Oxidoreductase and Methods for Preparing Such Food Ingredients and Food Products</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    8
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Food Interleaver, Method for Imparting Flavor to Food Product, and Combination Food Product and Food Interleaver</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    9
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-main">
  <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
   <div class="related-list-title">
    <a href="#">Liquid Food and Non-liquid Food</a>
   </div>
   <div class="related-list-sno">
    10
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="related-list-border-bot">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put code in the question itself - not images of code and not just a link to fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `vertical-align:middle` to the titles and  `vertical-align:top` to the numbers because `table-cell` is aligned by default `baseline`

Note: don't mix `float` with `table-cell`

```css
.related-list-main {
  width: 300px;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
}
.related-list-title {
  font: 12px Verdana, Arial, san-serif;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 85%;
  text-align: left;
  /* color: #337ab7; */
  vertical-align: middle
}
.related-list-sno {
  font: 22px Verdana, Arial, san-serif;
  color: #A51F1D;
  display: display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top
}
.related-list-border-bot {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #eceaea;
  margin: 0 0px;
  height: 1.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="patents" class="tab-pane in active ">
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Sea Food Flavored Food Products</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food Ingredients and Food Products Treated with an Oxidoreductase and Methods for Preparing Such Food Ingredients and Food Products</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food and Process for Producing Food</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Prepared Food for Functional Food</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food Ingredients and Food Products Treated with an Oxidoreductase and Methods for Preparing Such Food Ingredients and Food Products</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food Production Apparatus, the Production of Food and Novel Food Product</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food Production Apparatus for the Production of Food and Novel Food Product</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food Ingredients and Food Products Treated with an Oxidoreductase and Methods for Preparing Such Food Ingredients and Food Products</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Food Interleaver, Method for Imparting Flavor to Food Product, and Combination Food Product and Food Interleaver</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        9
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-main">
    <div style="display:table-row;width:100%">
      <div class="related-list-title">
        <a href="#">Liquid Food and Non-liquid Food</a>
      </div>
      <div class="related-list-sno">
        10
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="related-list-border-bot">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```